# echo on query result buggin

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am trying to extract the $row elemts with:

```
$sql = "SELECT date, email, journal, section FROM selection_loggedin WHERE email = '$email' and date in (SELECT max(date) FROM (SELECT date, email FROM selection_loggedin WHERE email = '$email') as x)";
$result = $dbc->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $journal = row['journal'];
    $section = row['section'];
    print_r($row);
    //echo "'$journal'"."'$section'";
    echo "<br>".row['email']."<br>";
    echo row['date']."<br>";
```

And I get this:

```
Array ( 
      [date] => 2017-05-07 12:45:45 
      [email] => benoitkoen@gmail.com 
      [journal] => Wall Street Journal 
      [section] => Economy 
)
```

Why doesn't it print the right stuff ('Wall Street Journal' and 'Economy')?

Comment: Because you're printing the whole `$row`, and you're selecting those columns as well in your `$sql` query. Are you expecting it to do something else?

Comment: print_r echos by default. Comment that line out.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I now understand the problem. You're trying to read the columns from `row`, where you should be reading from `$row` (note the `$`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT date, email, journal, section FROM selection_loggedin WHERE email = '$email' and date in (SELECT max(date) FROM (SELECT date, email FROM selection_loggedin WHERE email = '$email') as x)";
$result = $dbc->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $journal = $row['journal'];
    $section = $row['section'];
    print_r($row);
    //echo "'$journal'"."'$section'";
    echo "<br>".$row['email']."<br>";
    echo $row['date']."<br>";
```